# XCode 4 for Embedded Linux Kernel Development?

Tags: xcode, macos, cross-compiling, embedded-linux

I'm trying to use XCode 4 (with external build utility) for embedded Linux on ARM kernel development. Please note that I have all the cross-compilers and tools working from the command line on the Mac, but would like to use XCode for comfort.

The standard make phase (make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-none-eabi- uImage) seems to work just fine, but can't figure out how to:

(a) Create a target that needs interactive input in the shell (make ARCH=arm menuconfig). This always complains about "Error opening terminal: unknown", and as of XCode 4 it runs in the background. Any ideas how I can open an interactive shell in the foreground?

(b) Use arm-none-eabi-gdb as my debugger. This is optional but would be really neat.

Thanks!

Comment: have you done this successfully?

Answer (score 0):

a) Can you figure out how to launch the equivalent of an xterm containing the command?  Or some IDE's have a checkbox option to run a command in an interactive window.  Finally consider just doing any menuconfig-involved makes from the command line

b) Depends on if xcode can talk gdb's protocol in general.  If it can, then its a matter of figuring out the whole gdbserver target launch procedure.  If it can't you'll have to do text mode debugging or use a gdb-compatible front end.